# Заменяет знак вопроса при скачивании через wget

Tags: linux, wget

Скачиваю сайт с помощью команды:

> wget -r -l10 -k -nd -e robots=off  https://site.com -P /folder

И получается что если в странице сайта есть, например,

`<script src="script.js?AD0DD71A"></script>`

То на диске файл сохраняется с именем: **script.js%3FAD0DD71A**

Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

знак вопроса не очень хороший символ в имени файла. wget делает все правильно. Представьте себе, что удаленный сервер передаст имя файла в виде `../../etc/passwd`. И есть шансы, что все пойдет немного по другому. А удаленный сервер может в теории вписать туда все, что угодно.

Но если очень хочется, то можно wget попросить

```
--restrict-file-names=modes
```

где modes

- `unix` меняем`/` и control characters в диапазоне 0--31 и 128--159.
- `windows` меняем `\`, `|`, `/`, `:`, `?`, `"`, `*`, `<`, `>`, и control characters в диапазона 0--31 и 128--159. - это то, что срабатывает у Вас
- `nocontrol` - выключить замену символов (похоже, это то что Вам нужно, но оно опасно!)
- `ascii` - заменять все не аски символы (больше кода 127)
- `lowercase` - все в нижний регистр
- `uppercase` - все в верхний регистр

Думаю, что Вам нужно попробовать `--restrict-file-names=unix` или `--restrict-file-names=ascii`